# python code to run shell command in your local machine can not get user input password to switch to super user

Tags: python, shell, ssh

I was working to write a python code to run shell command through an SSH server. Now, I have trouble to get to switch to superuser.
The following is the code:
the following code is largely from this link:
https://daanlenaerts.com/blog/2016/01/02/python-and-ssh-sending-commands-over-ssh-using-paramiko/
and
http://jessenoller.com/2009/02/05/ssh-programming-with-paramiko-completely-different/

```
from paramiko import client
class ssh:
    client = None

    def __init__(self, address, username, password):
        print("Connecting to server.")
        self.client = client.SSHClient() # create a SSHclient object
        self.client.set_missing_host_key_policy(client.AutoAddPolicy()) #will auto accept unknown keys
        self.client.connect(address, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False) # connect us to the local SSH server

    def sendCommand(self, command):
        if(self.client):
            stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)

            if stdout is None or stdin is None or stderr is None:
                return
            while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
                # Print data when available
                if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
                    alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                    prevdata = b"1"
                    while prevdata:
                        prevdata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
                        alldata += prevdata

                    print(str(alldata, "utf8"))
        else:
            print("Connection not opened.")



connection = ssh("server_address","username","password")
connection.sendCommand("ls")

stdin, stdout, stderr = connection.sendCommand("su") # stdin: standard input; stdout: standard output; stderr: standard errors 

stdin.write('my_password')
stdin.flush()
connection.sendCommand("ls")
```

Error message:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = connection.sendCommand("su") # stdin: standard input; stdout: standard output; stderr: standard errors
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

After searching for this error message, it means the data is none. I'm confused. Could anyone help me out with this?
PS: I know there are some other ways to do this. I was just wondering, if I'd like to update this code, then what shall I do from here?

Comment: Maybe [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) will help.

Comment: a side question: suppose I can put this python code inside of the SSH connection, i.e., I open the terminal in my local computer, connect to my SSH server by enter my password. Navigate to my home directory and create and copy this python file there. I can run this python file there. In this case, I don't need to create a SSH connection again, since the python file is already inside of the SSH server, right? So, how to write a python code to execute SSH shell commands without creating the SSH connection? Or do I need to always create a connection in order to run shell commands?